# Anyobject is not a subtype of NSLayoutConstraint

Tags: swift, swift3

I am upgrading to Swift3, below code was working fine in Swift 2.3 but it is not working with Swift 3

```
    let constraints: NSArray = contentView.constraints as NSArray
    let indexOfConstraint = constraints.indexOfObject (passingTest: { (constraint, idx, stop) in
        return ((constraint as AnyObject).firstItem as! UIView).tag == bubbleTag && (constraint.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttribute.left || constraint.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttribute.right)
    })
```

I am getting following compiler error:

```
'(AnyObject)' is not a subtype of 'NSLayoutConstraint'
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might need something like this...

```
contentView.constraints.index(where: { constraint in
    guard let firstItemView = constraint.firstItem as? UIView else {
        return false
    }

    return firstItemView.tag == bubbleTag && (constraint.firstAttribute == .left || constraint.firstAttribute == .right)
})
```